# create 2d array dynamically and copy txt file. Segmentation error

Tags: c

I have keep getting segmentation error for this code. Any suggestions how to fix it? I know I am suppose to use free() after every malloc(), but I don't see how in my function since I am returning the created array. It;s weird this code works from home but not in school where I have to make it work. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void changeToLower(const char *regular, char *lowerCaseOnly)
{
    size_t ctr;
    size_t len = strlen(regular);
    int i=0;
    while(i<len) 
    {
        lowerCaseOnly[i] = tolower((unsigned char) regular[i]); 
        i++;    
    }
    lowerCaseOnly[len] = '\0';
}
char ** enterFile(int *size, char * nameofFile )
{
    int l;
    int ne;
    int messageSize         =165;
    char fname[40]          ;//="dictionary2.txt";
    FILE *file              =NULL;
    int i                   ;
    char **dArray           =NULL;
    int localsize           =0;
    if(strcmp(fname, "quit\n") == 0){
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Enter the name of the dictionary file you'd to use: ");
    fgets(fname,100, stdin);
    strtok(fname, "\n"); 
    strcpy(nameofFile,fname);
    file = fopen(fname,"r");
    if(file==NULL){ printf("Error could not find file;\n");}//In case file DNE
    fscanf(file, "%d", size);       
    localsize=(*(size)*2)+1;
    *size=localsize;
    //Allocation of memory for 2D array
    dArray =  malloc(localsize*sizeof( char*)); 
    for(i=0;i<localsize;i++){
        dArray[i]=malloc(messageSize*sizeof(char));
    }
    i=0;
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fgets(dArray[i],messageSize, file);
        strtok(dArray[i], "\n");
        i++;
    }   
    fclose(file);
    printf("Dictionary File Loaded\n");
    return dArray;    
}
int main()
{
    int size              =0;
    int ne, counter         ;
    char **dArray      =NULL;                   //pointer to array  DOUBLE ARRAY
    char option             ;
    int x                 =1;                                       //Neede DND
    char nameofDictionary[40]=" ";
    while(x!=5)
    {
        printf("|------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        printf("| Enter Option 1: To open dictionary file              |\n");
        scanf(" %c", & option);
        while((ne=getchar()) != '\n' && ne!= EOF );//====> DELETE
        //printf("You entered this option:\t %c\n", option);
        switch(option)
        {
        case '1':
            dArray=enterFile(&size, nameofDictionary);     
            //  printf("main file name now is: %s\n", nameofDictionary);
            break;
        case '2':
            //option2(dArray, &size);
            break;
        case '3':   
            //option3(dArray, &size);
            break;
        case '4':
            //dArray=option4(dArray,&size, nameofDictionary);
            //  printf("this should say futbol %s",dArray[151]);
            break;
        case '5':
            x=5;
            printf("Exit program.");
            break;
        default:
            printf(">>>>INVALID: Enter a valid input, try again\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

TEXTFILE only contains these sentences:

```
75
nevermind
nvm
not much
nm
no problem
np
people
ppl
talk to you later
ttyl
because
cuz
i don't know
idk
as soon as possible
asap
yeah
ya
how are you
hru
you
u
are
r
late
l8
at
@
good morning
gud morn
see you later
c u l8r
hello
lo
love
<3
as far as i know
afaik
away from keyboard
afk
thanks
thx
today
2day
before
b4
great
gr8
at the moment
atm
by the way
btw
oh my gosh
omg
rolling on the floor laughing
rofl
if i remember correctly
iirc
message
msg
please
plz
for your information
fyi
in my opinion
imo
just kidding
jk
you only live once
yolo
today
2day
tomorrow
2moro
tonight
2nite
alright
aight
also known as
aka
ask me anything
ama
with
w/
without
w/o
be right back
brb
on my way
omw
busy
bz
can
cn
cool
coo
disconnected
d/c
definitely
def
them
dem
too long; didn't read
tl;dr
estimated time of arrival
eta
favorite
fav
facebook
fb
got to go
g2g
good game
gg
good job
gj
congratulations
gratz
what
wat
i don't care
idc
i know, right
ikr
whatever
meh
minutes
mins
real life
rl
skater
sk8r
seriously
srsly
sorry
sry
whats up
sup
to be determined
tbd
throwback thursday
tbt
too much information
tmi
text
txt
thank you
ty
what the freak
wtf
```

Comment: Could you _shorten_ this file a bit?

Comment: This file is only long because of the dictionary files that are trivial

Comment: on which line does the debugger point? Please note that there's no such term 'Segmentation error', there is 'segmentation fault'

Comment: after printing line by line i think it happens in enterfile method after after the last line of using malloc and after the while loop

Comment: Wait, it can't happen in both places at once.

Comment: i meant to say in between. i after the second time the while loop tries to run fgets..

Comment: 0)`fgets(fname,100, stdin);` but `char fname[40]`

Comment: what do you mean/? BLUEPIXY

Comment: 1) `while(!feof(file))` change to `while(fgets(dArray[i], messageSize, file))`

Comment: I am getting segmentation error here:  
Line 95.==> int compare= strcmp(dArray[i],lowerCaseInput); I keep getting the same segmentation error again. I can t figure out why any suggestions??BLUEPIXy

Comment: `int compare= strcmp(dArray[i],lowerCaseInput);` Does not exist in the given code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is sadly lacking in error checking in many places. There is one particular place where you are likely to come unstuck due to this lack of error checking:

```
i=0;
while(!feof(file))
{
    fgets(dArray[i],messageSize, file);
    strtok(dArray[i], "\n");
    i++;
}
```

This makes no check to ensure that you limit `i` to the size of `dArray`, so you can easily go out of bounds here, e.g. if there are more lines than expected in the file. You might want to change the loop to:

```
i=0;
while (i < localSize && fgets(dArray[i], messageSize, file))
{
    strtok(dArray[i], "\n");
    i++;
}
```

Check the rest of your code for other such similar problems where lack of error checking might allow bad things to happen. Code defensively!

Comment: I need to free my pointers (after using malloc) any suggestions?

Comment: It's just the reverse operation of the `malloc`s - `free` each line in a loop and then `free` the array of pointers.

Comment: in this specific instance i need to return the array i created with malloc. can i free dArray in main???. BTW THANK YOU SOO MUCH

Comment: Sure - you can `free` it in `main`, when you're done with it.

Comment: in line Line 95.==> int compare= strcmp(dArray[i],lowerCaseInput); I keep getting the same segmentation error again. any suggestion Mr Paul R.  i will be so thankful

Comment: I don't even see that line in your code. Regardless, if you have a further problem, then you should try to debug it and then if you fail you should post a new question with the latest code, describing your exact problem and what you've tried so far.